# NavBar Android alternativo

Tags: android, menu

Quero fazer a minha propria NavBar, na qual quero apenas manter o botão "back" e criar outros botoes para chamar aplicações pre-definidas.
Deve funcionar como a NavBar original, ou seja estar sempre em cima de todas as aplicações e se o ecrã tiver 600px e a barra ocupar 100px o ecra disponivel para as aplicações deverá ser 500px...
Alguem sabe como fazer algo do genero?

Comment: Estamos no Stack Overflow em Português, traduza sua pergunta

Comment: Here we only answer questions in Portuguese, post your question in English [here](https://stackoverflow.com/)

Comment: Não sabia que este stack era só Portugues, parabens!